# Can't call my class in Python

Tags: python, class, call

I am writing a class in python to revise a line in a text file. The code is tested to be functioning well when running alone.

```
class fileeditor:
    def __init__ (self,a,b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = 0
        print 0
    def editinputfile (self):
        return 0
        with open (self.a,"r") as my_file:
           for line in my_file:
              if line.strip():
                  self.c+=1
        self.c=self.c-2
        with open (self.a,"r") as my_file:
            lines=my_file.readlines()
            lines[self.c]= self.b
        with open (self.a,"w") as my_file:
            my_file.write(''.join(lines))
        my_file.close()
```

But when i tried to call it from another file, it doesn't work. `self.a` is the address of the text file while `self.b` is the string that will overwrite one line in the text file.

```
from editor import fileeditor
a=".\test.txt"
b='1 2 4 5\n'
fileeditor(a, b)
```

Comment: Please describe *how* it "doesn't work".  What happens?

Comment: Just checking: is it intentional that `editinputfile` does nothing? Any statement occurring after a `return` will never execute.

Comment: Do you get any output at all?

Comment: the text file is not changed.

Comment: "return 0" is just used to be debugging. When i delete it, also not work.

Comment: In the first place, like Kevin said, `editinputfile` won't do anything.  In the second place, you never call it anyway.

Comment: I can't understand why i didn't call it. Any suggestion to revise the codes?

Comment: Thanks. you are right. Thanks for your suggestion, as a new Pythoner, really appreciate your help.

Comment: As a side note, if you're using Python 2, never define classes like `class foo:`, always do `class foo(object):`. Otherwise, you bring in all kinds of quirks related to old-style classes, which you don't want to have to learn.

Comment: @Wei just to remind you can accept an answer if you want...

Answer (score 4):

By the example you gave it seems that you are only creating the new instance but not calling the `editinputfile` method. Try to do:

```
fe = fileeditor(a, b)
fe.editinputfile()
```

Comment: Or OP could include a call to ```editinputfile()``` in ```__init__()``` if he/she always wants it to happen (which I think is the case)

Comment: @wnnmaw indeed that's true, but then it would make more sense to have a function instead of a class...

Comment: Very true, maybe it should just be a function, or OP could have other code that makes it worth being a class that just wasn't included in the question.  I just thought I'd point it out anyways

Comment: Can you detailed explain how to include a call of editinputfile() in __init__()?

Comment: @user3233598 after the line `print 0` (whatever it means...) you can add the line `self.editinputfile()` and that's all...

Comment: @Wei since you are pretty new here it is worth mentioning that you can accept the answer [clicking on the arrow at the left side](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234)

Answer (score 1):

First you should remove `return 0` in `editinputfile`. Then you should also call this function.

```
from editor import fileeditor
a=".\test.txt"
b='1 2 4 5\n'
myfe = fileeditor(a, b)
myfe.editinputfile()
```